# Postgres Vacuum doesnt free up space

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

I have a table in my database which is occupying 161GB hard disk space. Only 5 gb free space is left out of 200Gb harddisk.

1. The following command shows that my table is consuming 161GB harddisk space,
   `select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('Employee'));`
2. There are close to 527 rows in the table. Now I deleted 250 rows. Again I checked the pg_total_relation_size of Employee. Still the size is 161GB.
3. After seeing the output of the above query, I ran the vacuum command:
   `VACUUM VERBOSE ANALYZE Employee;`
4. I checked if the VACUUM actually happened using,
   `SELECT relname, last_vacuum, last_autovacuum FROM pg_stat_user_tables;`
   I can see the last vacuum time matching the time I ran the VACUUM command.
5. I also ran the below command to see if there any dead tuples,
   `SELECT relname, n_dead_tup FROM pg_stat_user_tables`;
   n_dead_tup count for Employee table is 0.
6. Still after all these above commands if I run,
   `select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('Employee'));`
   it still shows 161GB.

May I please know the reason behind this? Also please correct me on how to free interface_list.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`vacuum` doesn't physically "free" space. It only marks no longer used space as re-usable. So subsequent UPDATE or INSERT statements can use that space instead of appending to the table.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-BASICS)

> The standard form of `VACUUM` removes dead row versions in tables and indexes and *marks the space available for future reuse*. However, **it will not return the space to the operating system**, except in the special case where one or more pages at the end of a table become entirely free and an exclusive table lock can be easily obtained

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

If you re-insert the 250 deleted rows, you will see that the table doesn't grow again, as the newly inserted rows simply use the space that was marked free by `vacuum`.

If you actually want to physically reduce the size of the table to size that is "needed", you need to run `vacuum full`.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-SPACE-RECOVERY)

> `VACUUM FULL` actively compacts tables by writing a complete new version of the table file **with no dead space**. This minimizes the size of the table, but can take a long time. It also requires extra disk space for the new copy of the table, until the operation completes

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>